# project.exe has triggered a breakpoint cause by dynamic allocation

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

i'm writing patcher in c++ and as part of the project i'm writing dissasembler using Zydis, im sending the memory opcode to function that basicly take every byte casting it to dec and push it into an array, the function will return a struct of pointer to the array and his size. the point is that in the caller function - after the call to the function, i'm trying to allocate memory in the size of the returned size.

```
ZyanU8* data = new ZyanU8[temp.size];
```

In runtime i'm get error of "project.exe has triggered a breakpoint", actually its happen in every big size of allocate, it also has nothing to do with the fact that this it's type is ZyanU8, i have tried it with int and i get the same
how can i fix it?

```
struct memArray
{
    int* arr;
    int size;
};

memArray convert_to_ZyanU8(DWORD* Total, DWORD size)
{
    int size_ = 0;
    int* dwTA=new int[(size/0x400)*0x100];
    for (int j = 0; j < size / 0x400; j++)//understand size
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 0x100; i++)
        {
            char buffer[9];
            sprintf_s(buffer, "%x", Total[j*0x100+i]);
            int counter = 0;
            for (int n = 0; n < 8; n+=2)
            {
                unsigned int xfirst;
                std::stringstream sfirst;
                sfirst << std::hex << *(buffer+n);
                sfirst >> xfirst;
                unsigned int xsecond;
                std::stringstream ssecond;
                ssecond << std::hex << *(buffer+n+1);
                ssecond >> xsecond;
                dwTA[j*0x100+i*4 + counter] = xfirst*16+xsecond;
                ++counter;
                ++size_;
                if (size_ == 12287)
                    int a = 3;
            }
        }
    }
    memArray memarray;
    memarray.arr = dwTA;
    memarray.size = size_;
    return memarray;
}


void ZydisDA(DWORD* Total,DWORD size)
{
    memArray temp = convert_to_ZyanU8(Total, size);
    ZyanU8* data = new ZyanU8[temp.size];
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size; ++i)
    {
        data[i] = temp.arr[i];
    }
    // Initialize decoder context
    ZydisDecoder decoder;
    ZydisDecoderInit(&decoder, ZYDIS_MACHINE_MODE_LONG_COMPAT_32,ZYDIS_ADDRESS_WIDTH_32);

    // Initialize formatter. Only required when you actually plan to do instruction
    // formatting ("disassembling"), like we do here
    ZydisFormatter formatter;
    ZydisFormatterInit(&formatter, ZYDIS_FORMATTER_STYLE_INTEL);

    // Loop over the instructions in our buffer.
    // The runtime-address (instruction pointer) is chosen arbitrary here in order to better
    // visualize relative addressing
    ZyanU64 runtime_address = 0x00401000;
    ZyanUSize offset = 0;
    const ZyanUSize length = temp.size;
    ZydisDecodedInstruction instruction;
    while ((ZydisDecoderDecodeBuffer(&decoder, data + offset, length - offset, &instruction)))
    {
        // Print current instruction pointer.
        printf("%016" PRIX64 "  ", runtime_address);

        // Format & print the binary instruction structure to human readable format
        char buffer[256];
        ZydisFormatterFormatInstruction(&formatter, &instruction, buffer, sizeof(buffer),        runtime_address);
        puts(buffer);

        offset += instruction.length;
        runtime_address += instruction.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: This could be a result of heap corruption that occurred at some time before the crash. You will likely have to debug. If that is not helping you may want to add some logging to your code to track the use of new and delete and the allocation sizes. A second option is to use a program like valgrind or AddressSanitizer to help you with that.

Comment: You can extract the bytes of a `DWORD` with bitshifting. There's no need to detour through strings.

Comment: Your code is error-prone and slow, please provide a minimal able, reproducible program.